# How to add default values to group by & count in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

is there option to set "default" values to `groupBy`?

For example I have column cars where values are inserted from enum (BMW, Porsche, Audi itd.).

I would like to group by and count this cars:

```
select brand, count(*)
from cars
group by brand
```

If there are values with all of this enum in database, then its ok - results are like this:

```
BMW | 3
Audi | 4
Jaguar | 5
```

But if I have in database only cars with BMW result is only BMW:

```
BMW | 3
```

and **there is my question** - how to add default fields to have response like:

```
BMW | 3
Audi | 0
Mercedes | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list the values somehow.  One method uses a `values` clause:

```
select brand, count(c.brand)
from (values ('BMW'), ('Audi'), ('Jaguar')) v(brand) left join
     cars c
     using (brand)
group by brand;
```

In practice, you should have the brands in their own table, so you could use:

```
select brand, count(c.brand)
from brands b
     cars c
     using (brand)
group by brand;
```

Comment: What in the world is `v(brand)`?